# Understanding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

[image]

As per the image shown above, I have some queries. It is requested to read each step in order :-

1. Each block is an Android Activity
2. Arrow represents the Stack Direction - the order in which activities are opened(A is started when the app was first launched)
3. Here when the User reaches **ACTIVITY F** and want to open **activity Z** (We are using Flag_Activity_clear_top) for the same.
4. After that from **ACtivity Z** when the user wants to open the **Activity D**.

****Our Requirement at this step is - When the Activity D is opened and the user do presses the back button - I WANT THAT USER SHOULD BE REDIRECTED BACK TO THE **ACTIVITY C**, AFTER THAT **ACTIVITY B** and so on..** **

Currently when we press back from the **activity D**(after coming from Z), then we are being redirected to the **Activity Z**.

Comment: your question is not much clear..

Comment: its normal coz you clear the activity stack

Comment: @Raghunandan I know it is obvious, My question is how to achieve the same which I want - have described above.Our Requirement at this step is - When the Activity D is opened and the user do presses the back button - I WANT THAT USER SHOULD BE REDIRECTED BACK TO THE *ACTIVITY C, AFTER THAT ACTIVITY B and so on.

Comment: @samsad suggest you check this http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html.

Answer (score 5):

CLEAR_TOP isn't good, because if you open an activity that way, it will remove the whole stack and that doesn't sound like what you want.

Try this:
When starting activity E (from D), F (from E) and Z (from F), do it with the flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY". This flag will prevent the new activity to appear in the back stack.

Keep in mind that any activity you open this way will not be registered in the back stack. So, if you hit back while (for example) you're in F, it will return to D.

Hope this helps!

Comment: why the downvote? this will enable the exact behavior you requested.

Comment: Gil, dont worry, stackoverflow users likes downvoting and not saying why

Answer (score 0):

->Incase anyone is facing the same issue. Try sending the intent along with the flags 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP' and 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP'.

->Example mentioned in the docs: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

> Consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receives the sentIntent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.